# How to react to Bitbucket PR comments via Rest API

Tags: powershell, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I have a Bitbucket Server and I'm trying to figure out how to react to PR comments via the REST API. I'm referencing [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v815/api-group-pull-requests/#api-comment-likes-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-pull-requests-pullrequestid-comments-commentid-reactions-emoticon-put). The example shows:

```bash
curl --request PUT \
  --url 'http://{baseurl}/rest/comment-likes/latest/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests/{pullRequestId}/comments/{commentId}/reactions/{emoticon}' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

But I don't know what it's looking for, for `{emoticon}` do I send a literal emoticon in the URL? Do I use the Unicode value? The value in the documentation just says `string`, which isn't very helpful for emoticons.

I'm using PowerShell (`Invoke-RestMethod`) so I tried these values for `{emoticon}`:

```
[char]0x1F602
[convert]::ToInt32("1F602", 16)
[char]::ConvertFromUtf32([convert]::ToInt32("1F602", 16))
```

All of them got various errors like `400 Bad Request`.

But aside from the PowerShell piece, if anyone could give insight as to what sort of input they're  actually looking for, I could figure out how to do it in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, it seems it's looking for names of the emoticons. So this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri 'http://{baseurl}/rest/comment-likes/latest/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests/{pullRequestId}/comments/{commentId}/reactions/heart
```

Adds a heart. "smile" adds a smile. But then "laugh" doesn't work but "laughing" does. So now I just need to figure out which names Bitbucket uses for all the rest of the emoticons, or find a list somewhere.